# GCM - How to send notification to multiple device targets with different message contents in java

Tags: java, android

I need to send different message contents to different device targets

```
final List<String> androidTargets = new ArrayList<String>();
serverSender.send(gcmMessage, androidTargets, 1);
```

I can add multiple device targets with same message however I need to add multiple messages related to that target like:

```
List<String> messages
```

Message index need to be mapped to device target

Is there any possibility to achieve this? I need this since I want to send notification in a single shot instead of queuing in my side!

Comment: how long is the message to be sent? I mean how many parts? the best way could be an array of messages

Comment: I guess sending GCM is a task for server instead of android application. You can create some API on a server side and send some special info/data using that API and then server should do all the rest according to received data.

Comment: Yes talking about server. In my Api always received different message contents & it need to be sent to different device tokens. For E.g., Two different messages ("Hello Sam", "Hello Paul") & have to send this message to two different device tokens respectively (Sam & Paul's). If for a same single message I can just add two device tokens by calling androidTargets.add(deviceToken) & simply send it with serverSender.send("Hi", androidTargets, 1) But now I need to call this serverSender.send() method for multiple times since always my message contents will be different for different device tokens.

Comment: @Saqib: Could you direct me to map array of messages in Java before send it from server?